# Problem with saving data in tables in asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005-express

Hello i have a problem with my application today it encountered a major problem :

I'm using vs2008 prof with it's sql server 2005 express edition.

The problem is that when i try to make an update on a row in one table the update.executeNonQuery() returns the value 1 that means that there was 1 row updated but the row is not updated.

If i try to modify the value manually by opening the table data and modifying a field it works and it saves but otherwise it does nothing.

I also tried to run it on a different machine with the same software kit and the same thing also tried to run it by IIS7 and the problem is not going away.

Can anybody give some suggestions of what should i do or if anyone encountered this problem i really need the help and i will highly appreciate it!

Later Edit : -- Added the source code

```
    int user_id = (int)Session["UserId"];
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand("update profil_candidat set nume = @pnume, prenume = @pprenume, data_nasterii = @pdata_nasterii, id_oras = @pid_oras , adresa = @padresa where id_utilizator=@pid_utilizator",con);
    update.Parameters.Add("pnume", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    update.Parameters.Add("pprenume", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    update.Parameters.Add("pdata_nasterii", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    update.Parameters.Add("pid_oras", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    update.Parameters.Add("padresa", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    update.Parameters.Add("pid_utilizator",SqlDbType.Int);
    int an = Convert.ToInt32(AnDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value);
    int luna = Convert.ToInt32(LunaDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value);
    int zi = Convert.ToInt32(ZiDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value);
    DateTime data = new DateTime(an, luna, zi);
    update.Parameters["pnume"].Value = TextBoxNume.Text;
    update.Parameters["pprenume"].Value = TextBoxPrenume.Text;
    update.Parameters["pdata_nasterii"].Value = data;
    update.Parameters["pid_oras"].Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
    update.Parameters["padresa"].Value = TextBoxAdresa.Text;
    update.Parameters["pid_utilizator"].Value = int.Parse(Session["UserId"].ToString());
    update.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

---

Later edit

Issue solved seems that in fact it was related to :

[C# Update Table using SqlCommand.Parameters ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966275/c-update-table-using-sqlcommand-parameters-asp-net)

somebody forgot to put the form initialization in the page load in an if(Page.IsPostBack) and there was nothing wrong with the dbase but the parameters sent in the statement were always preloaded on event... still thank you for the prompt answers !

Comment: Could you please post the data access code (C#) that you are using so we can tell where the problem is

Comment: did you try to debug the TSQL & C# code? that should be first step.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I ran into this it was a permissions issue.  For whatever reason SQL server wasn't returning the proper error message and instead was indicating that the underlying table was being updated... even though it wasn't.

Connect to your SQL Express instance using the exact same credentials as you have in your web.config.  Then execute the same query and see what happens.

Comment: It works great for other components like register that does modification and I'm using a .mdf file and everything else can access it. Also tried to run an update from the query builder and it works just fine all columns got updated and it is the exact same update from my page

Answer (score -1):

If `executeNonQuery` is returning 1, then it probably is updating successfully *somewhere*, otherwise you should get an exception thrown or it would return `0`. Check your connection string in your web.config and verify that your site is pointing to the database that you think it is.

**Update**:

The part of your connection string `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS` means you are connecting to the SQL Server instance named `SQLEXPRESS` on localhost, so if you're deploying your project to a different computer, it will no longer be connecting to the same .mdf file that's stored on your computer, it will be using the .mdf file on the other computer. See this MSDN blog article for more details on working with a User Instance database and connecting to it from Server Management Studio:

[Connecting to SQL Express User Instances in Management Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2006/11/22/connecting-to-sql-express-user-instances-in-management-studio.aspx)

Comment: There are two connection strings in my web.config both pointing at the exact same mdf file. I executed the update statement from the server explorer interface and it worked just fine and it was the exact same thing. Also tried to see if it throws any exceptions but it works fine according to the application.

Comment: Can you provide the connection string from your web.config? If your connectionstring has something like `User Instance=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf"` in it, then when you deploy your site, it's not updating the .mdf in your development environment, it's updating the .mdf on the server in the folder that `|DataDirectory|` points to.

Comment: <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\getjob().mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: @Bogdan I updated my answer, there was too much to fit in a comment.